# Recursive first day of each month for current getdate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, I want a new column that will show me the first day of each month, for the current year of getdate(). 
After that I need to count the rows on this specific date. Should I do it with CTE or a temp table?

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+, you can use **DateFromParts()**

**To Get a List of Dates**

```
Select D = DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),N,1) 
 From (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) N(N)
```

**Returns**

```
D
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
2017-04-01
2017-05-01
2017-06-01
2017-07-01
2017-08-01
2017-09-01
2017-10-01
2017-11-01
2017-12-01
```

> **Edit For Trans Count**

To get Transactions (assuming by month).  It becomes a small matter of a left join to created Dates

```
-- This is Just a Sample Table Variable for Demonstration.  
-- Remove this and Use your actual Transaction Table
--------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @Transactions table (TransDate date,MoreFields int)
Insert Into @Transactions values
 ('2017-02-18',6)
,('2017-02-19',9)
,('2017-03-05',5)


Select TransMonth = A.MthBeg
      ,TransCount = count(B.TransDate)
 From (
        Select MthBeg = DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),N,1) 
              ,MthEnd = EOMonth(DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),N,1))
         From (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) N(N)
      ) A
 Left Join @Transactions B on TransDate between MthBeg and MthEnd
 Group By A.MthBeg
```

Returns

```
TransMonth  TransCount
2017-01-01  0
2017-02-01  2
2017-03-01  1
2017-04-01  0
2017-05-01  0
2017-06-01  0
2017-07-01  0
2017-08-01  0
2017-09-01  0
2017-10-01  0
2017-11-01  0
2017-12-01  0
```

Comment: Thanks!could you please provide a small explanation of your thinking?

Comment: @Proffesore The FROM portion generates 12 records (1-12) with a field name of N.  Then we simply use N as the month in DateFromParts().  ...DateFromPart(year,month,day) ...

Answer (score 1):

For an adhoc table of months for a given year:

```
declare @year date = dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate() ),0)
;with Months as (
  select 
      MonthStart=dateadd(month,n,@year)
  from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) t(n)
)
select MonthStart
from Months
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/POKPM51023

returns:

```
+------------+
| MonthStart |
+------------+
| 2017-01-01 |
| 2017-02-01 |
| 2017-03-01 |
| 2017-04-01 |
| 2017-05-01 |
| 2017-06-01 |
| 2017-07-01 |
| 2017-08-01 |
| 2017-09-01 |
| 2017-10-01 |
| 2017-11-01 |
| 2017-12-01 |
+------------+
```

The first part: `dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate() ),0)` adds the number of years since `1900-01-01` to the date `1900-01-01`. So it will return the first date of the year. You can also swap `year` for other levels of truncation: year, quarter, month, day, hour, minute, second, et cetera.

The second part uses a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [table value constructor `(values (...),(...))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) to source numbers 0-11, which are added as months to the start of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you require recursive... But for first day of month you can try query like below:

```
Select Dateadd(day,1,eomonth(Dateadd(month, -1,getdate())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @year date = dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate() ),0)
;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
(
SELECT 0
UNION ALL
SELECT MonthNumber+1 
FROM months
WHERE MonthNumber < 11
)
select  dateadd(month,MonthNumber,@year)
from months
```